# How can I style Native component in react Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using a custom Native Component to render video (in a video calling application) and I want to design the video itself in React Native here is code,

```
import { CustomizedNativeComponent } from './../...';
videoComponent={
                        <CustomizedNativeComponent style = {{ height:'10%', borderColor:'red', borderWidth:'5px' }} />
                    }
```

I dont see any changes on video , can someone suggest what I am doing wrong here, also I am new to React Native

Comment: Try putting the video component inside a View, and apply the styles to the View

Comment: unfortunately that did not work , can I wrap it in Image to use resizeMode ?

Comment: No, an image will require a binary image source.  Sorry that didn't work.